# Snapshot from UIView with huge bounds is not rendered

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I defined snapshot in code:

```
extension UIView {
    var snapshot: UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size)
        let image = renderer.image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        }
        return image
    }
}
```

Output for size `(2384.0, 3370.3333333333335)` is completely black, although there is a lot of content inside.

This is what I get on console:

> 2023-04-24 08:09:21.348283+0200 Territories[3442:9511143] [Unknown process name] CGImageCreateMaskFromAlpha: Unsupported bitsPerComponent (16, must be 8) or bitsPerPixel (64, must be 32)
> 2023-04-24 08:09:21.630013+0200 Territories[3442:9511529] [Metal] 7152 by 10111 iosurface is too large for GPU

This is how I call it:

I add two views to my view hierarchy:

```
addSubview(wrapperView)
wrapperView.backgroundColor = .orange        
wrapperView.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
    maker.leading.top.equalToSuperview()
    maker.width.equalTo(2384)
    maker.height.equalTo(3370)
}

wrapperView.addSubview(mapContainerView)
mapContainerView.backgroundColor = .red
mapContainerView.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
    maker.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
}
let scale = 0.16359492667459377
wrapperView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
wrapperView.snp.updateConstraints { maker in
    maker.leading.equalTo(-997)
    maker.top.equalTo(-1360)
}
```

And this is how it looks like on the screen:

[image]

I do a snapshot on a wrapperView (orange one). Here's where I do that:

```
let document = PDFDocument()
let page = PDFPage(image: mainView.wrapperView.snapshot)!
document.insert(page, at: document.pageCount)
```

Comment: Can you show how/where you're calling this extension, at a quick glance that should return the proper image assuming the child views are added properly and you're calling on the right view.

Comment: in drawHierarchy you can set you own bound and get output as same bound you assigned.

Comment: I wonder if your "Where?" question needs to be expanded into a full sentence to be more readily understood. Would you edit the post?

Comment: What's the question? As the error message explains to you, at your screen resolution you are asking for an image 7152 by 10111, which is immense and won't fit in the GPU used for snapshotting with `drawHierarchy`.

Comment: @matt I didnt expect there are limitations for this. Is there a way to workaround it? ANy other idea how to print map on A0? Is it really hard to print on A0 size?

Comment: What "map" are we talking about?

Comment: @matt I simply create a view with dimension in px that is suitable for A0. And inside I add a subview with a map (here is Mapbox, but it may be anything like google, apple). And I would like to print A0 sheet from within an app ready for print on printer. So I simply do a snapshot of my scaled view in an app, and create a PDFDocument, than share it using UIActivityController... but here for A0 my snapshot is black... because it is too large...‍♂️ so I dont know what to do next

Comment: And this doesn't work either? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I am not sure how should I use it, because it returns UIView, when I need UIImage... However when I called it first and then snapshot on returned view... it doesnt work either‍♂️ I think, there is no way to do it for A0, it works only on maximum A1.